ASP.NET MVC application and an ASP.NET API Login using using Azure AD
Suppose I have two projects: an ASP.NET MVC application and an ASP.NET API. I am using Azure AD for authentication in the MVC application and want the same access token to also grant access to the ASP.NET API. Could you advise on the best practices for implementing this? Additionally, does the following approach make sense: When a user logs into the MVC app, I want to redirect them to an account controller to verify whether the user is registered with the application. This would involve sending a request to the API to retrieve all roles and claims, and then updating the default claims in Azure AD, as all my claims originate from the API database. Is this a feasible and secure approach?
but noting working for me can some please help ref me youtube clip for some article
ASP.net MVC upsetting and  Program.cs
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/Account/LogOn",
  },
        builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApplication2Context>();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
   builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                      .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

**ASP.NET API program.cs and upsetting **
just adding
    builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

api config
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",


  },


are  both dependent? totally two different projects?

totally different projects
